# WebView takes minutes to load local html

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a simple html page (text + images) in external storage directory.

After I pass to webview its url (something like "file:///sdcard/test/test.html"), it may sometimes take up to 5 minutes to load. There is a maximum of 3 images per html and all of them are small (up to 300KB), so it can't be caching related issue.

The code is the following (mDescription is a WebView here):

```
mDescription.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
mDescription.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mDescription.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
mDescription.loadUrl(url);
```

What's going on?

Comment: is there anything interesting in logcat?

Comment: Not really, no serious GC activity, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator or with a real device?

Comment: Real device - Galaxy Tab 2.

Comment: Also, this behavior is uneven. Sometimes pages load quickly. It seems to vary with builds (that have no differences concerning activity where this is happening).

Comment: Got this issue on Nexus 4 / 4.4.2 loading jpg from assets-folder.